# JupyterLite not running anything

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter

I'm using JupyterLite as it is very comfortable to do so, but sometimes it simply won't work. To be clear, once I set the kernel (usually Pyodide) then it may happen that it will not run even the first line:

```
%pylab inline
```

being my first one. Yes I know that pylab is now deprecated but the problem is that no line will run, at this point I guess the problem is with the kernel itself? I tried changing it, with no results.

Comment: First, JupyterLite is highly experimental. It is changing rapidly and you'll need to update consistently. It can indeed be slow to start up. I was just testing a cell with import of piplite and then install of ipympl. It errored the first time. And this is the offered demo site offering of a demo noteboook. So you'll need to be accepting of quirks if you are going to bushwhack where you've been told ' here there be dragons'. That said, you aren't telling what you've found with different first cells in your experience? Something that isn't deperecated. More like `2 + 2`. Is it possible it is...

Comment: <continued> a memory issue as that pylab magic command triggers bringing in all of numpy and matplotlib into the namespace? Is it only this command that causes this behavior? Any better in a different browser?